# Validate a SHA256 (python generated) in C

Tags: python, c, sha256

I'm trying to validate a hash generated by python using the passlib (https://passlib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/lib/passlib.hash.sha256_crypt.html) in C code using openssl/sha.h.

For the password "senhateste" the python passlib has generated the following hash:

```
$5$rounds=535000$e.cy1Y7iWc0OQjNC$7QbwABQMlBdHHd.UURPF.eoc0VTGOtM7yxxrOIe4OxC
```

where there is a number of rounds, a salt and a checksum (separated by $).

I was trying to generate a hash for the raw password in C to compare with the one generated by Python code, but I got only an array of bytes (like the ones of online sha256 hash tools).

I was thinking in make a loop hashing the password for the same number of rounds provided by Pyhton. But I can't figure out where I should use the salt.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <openssl/sha.h>

int main (void) {
     int i;
     unsigned char s[] = "senhateste";
     unsigned char *d = (unsigned char *) malloc(SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH);

    SHA256(s,strlen((char*)s), d);

    for(i=0;i<SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH;i++)
    {
        printf("%02x",d[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    free(d);
   return 0;
}
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: If you're using GLIBC, see `crypt(3)`.

Comment: Or otherwise, see the spec (Drepper was GLIBC lead developer for a *long* time): https://akkadia.org/drepper/SHA-crypt.txt